# Translating loop from MatLab to Python

Tags: python, matlab, loops

I have the following loop that goes through a matrix in matlab:

```
for i=1:n
    for j=i+1:n
```

I want to translate the for loop into python. I tried:

```
for i in range(N)
     for j in range(i+N)
```

But I'm not sure it does exactly the same.  How can I write a loop that does the same in Python?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: No etc. doesnt matter. Im only interested in the loop definition, specifically the loop over j :-) i.e. does for j in range (i+N) do the same as for j=i+1:N

Answer (score 0):

1) for loops need a colon at the end of the line

2) matrices in matlab are indexed with 1 to N, in python with 0 to (N-1)

3) range(N) gives you the numbers 0 to (N-1)